# How to find a formula using a table of values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given a table of values to find a formula for h(t). The values for t: 2, 5, 8, 11. And the values for h: 10, 8, 6, 4. And the homework question asks me to find a formula for h(t). And it also asks me to find the intercepts for t and h. So I'm wondering how to solve this homework problem because I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have been given that:

$$h(t) =\begin{cases}10&:& t=2\\ 8 &:& t = 5\\ 6 &:& t = 8\\ 4 &:& t = 11\\\text{unknown} &:& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

But you have also been asked "*to find the intercepts for t and h.*"  This indicates that these known points belong to a line:  $$h(t)=mt+c$$

[Plotting on a graph will confirm.]

So, we are asked what line passes through the points: $\{\langle 2,10 \rangle, \langle 5,8 \rangle, \langle 8,6 \rangle, \langle 11, 4\rangle\}$

Ie, solve for the gradient and $y$ intercept, $m,c$ of the simultaneous equations: $$10=2m+c\\ 8=5m+c\\ 6=8m+c\\ 4=11m+c$$

Then find the intercepts, $h_0, t_0$ where:  $h_0=c$ and $0=t_0 m+c$